# Screen flow format decimal places

Tags: visual-workflow, formatting

I have a screen flow that is displaying a currency field from an object with two decimal places. The problem is that if the decimal part is .00, it is completely dropping the decimal places. Below is the field on the screen definition, where Get_Company is the previous step in the flow that queries the company.

Current Price:  {!Get_Company.Current_Price__c}

So, for example, if the price comes back as 45.00, it will show like this on the page:

Current Price: 45

when I want it to display as:

Current Price: 45.00

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You will have to roll your own mechanism to do this. It might be good to up vote [this idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000IAXwBUAX/improve-currency-support-to-better-support-packaged-currency-handling) as well since the number of decimal places you need varies by currency.

Comment: Thanks, @phil-w. I did roll my own. Answering my question below on how I did it.

Answer (score 1):

Having to roll my own, I created a formula field on my object named current_price_formatted__c based on a post online (see [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000Aeo1IAC)) that uses the below formula which did the trick.

```
text( floor( Current_Price__c ) ) +
"." +
right( text( ( 1 + Current_Price__c - floor( Current_Price__c ) ) * 100 ), 2 )
```

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Always good to cite where you found the solution too. Of course, this is only good for a subset of possible currencies since the number of decimal places required varies between 0 and 5 depending on the currency.

Comment: I'm fortunate that this is not a multi-currency org, so I only have to worry about U.S. dollars. I also found the link I used in another browser profile, so I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know maybe it's a bit too late to answer that but I was facing this situation today and found your question. What I did was: create a formula variable (type currency) in the flow and put the currency field you want to show in that variable and then show the variable in the screen component instead of the field directly.

This way all the decimal places are shown even if they are 00, also the currency sign is shown too.